# Building a completely custom map in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, frontend

I'm currently trying to create an app to help route users while they're inside an enclosed location like a **mall** or a **school**. I've built up a framework to generate maps of these locations and exported them as images. I was planning on using these images as the map to display on the frontend to somehow draw routes on the images to guide the user. I just can't think of a simple way to do this.

I've seen `react-native-maps` but that just seems to use the standard Google maps view and doesn't let me use a custom map to draw routes on. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what level of detail you want, you might be able to do this with an overlay or custom map tiles.

You can overlay your map over google maps using the [overlay layer on react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/overlay.md). If this amount of detail is not enough, you could try creating a tile server to get images or use vector tiles with MapBox maps(which also has some nice react-native bindings).

As for drawing routes, it should be straightforward by using a [poly line layer](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/polyline.md). You'll have to calculate the paths beforehand and draw them using a poly line.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a custom map in React Native with `react-native-maps` and `maptiler`. The idea is to create a custom design of a real map (in my case, of a certain city) and overlap it on the real map. That way, you can use the user's location to track them accurately. You can also use the `setMapBoundaries` function in `react-native-maps` so that the user doesn't leave the overlapped area.

This is most common used for games that include interaction with real world locations.